# Relay how to use multiple fragments in ViewerQueries file

Tags: relay

I want to use multiple fragments in queries file

**Like For home page i am using route as following and passing viewqueries file to it**

```
indexRoute: {
            component: Index,
            queries: ViewerQueries,
            prepareParams: () => ({status: 'any'}),
        },
```

**In ViewerQueries file m using**

```
export default {
fitment: () => Relay.QL`query { fitment }`,
};
```

**Above code is working fine but i have a cart in header so i need to add also cart fragment with every query, and i am adding it as follows**

```
export default {
fitment: () => Relay.QL`query { fitment }`,
cart: () => Relay.QL`query { cart }`,
};
```

on adding this its giving me following error
**Invariant Violation: Relay(Home).getFragment(): `cart` is not a valid fragment name. Available fragments names: `fitment`**

Can anyone help? Thank you in advance

Comment: Does your server-side schema object has top level query field `cart` in addition to `fitment`?

Comment: wondering the same.